# Is there any app.config file in C# as like in vb?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config, video-conferencing

In Windows application using vb.net a APP.config file is created automatically. Is that file is created in windows application developed using C# ? If yes then where can I find it ?
As I'm developing a project in ASP.net in which I've to use a web application for video conferencing, for which I'm using iconf.net dll files from AVSpeed. In which I've to enable flag for realtime application which is in APP.config file as said.

Comment: yes, you can also do it manually app.config

Comment: if you make a connection to your database using server explorer, it will create it for you i.e app.config

Comment: asp.net applications will use the `web.config` file.  You can put all your appsettings there.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please elaborate..

Comment: Yes, of course C# supports an "app.config".  For Console, Winforms or WPF apps.  It's in your project root; a copy is in your Debug or Release subdirectory.  For ASP.Net web apps, the file will be "web.config" instead.

Comment: Regardless of the language used, for `ASP.NET` you would need a `web.config` file. If you create your project using a VS template, you will get the `web.config` file straight away.

Comment: I've checked my debug folder but couldn't find any app.config file..
even I checked all the web application folder from top to down with failure in hand.

Comment: I've voted to close it. Honestly I believe that `web.config` or `app.config` configuration files are a very very basic step  in .NET learning and there's an impressive amount of information around both in MSDN and also here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Newbie here in .NET who needs help, no offense.

Comment: @1binary0 Everyone was a newbie. I believe your question is someway impulsive, you know. I would be searching the basic ASP.NET app structure on MSDN rather than coming and let others do the same for you! ;)

Comment: Vote up buddy. Thanks for en lighting . Next time I'll do my homework then, thanks :-)

Comment: 1binary0, Please avoid thank you notes, and especially "urgent help please". "urgent" is generally not welcome here. If you really need something urgent - pay someone to get it done quickly (or call 911 :) )

Comment: Acknowledged, Roger that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new windows application in C# then by default you dont get any app config file. To answer your question, Yes C# does support appconfig files. You can add them as shown below :

[image]

Then you can exploit its XML to set some values as shown in the example below.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestFlag" value="false" />
    <add key="TestUser" value="somevalue" />
    <add key="TestPass" value="somevalue" />
    <add key="TestRole" value="SA" />
    <add key="TestModeOfOp" value="dssaas" />
    <add key="TestFetchRef" value="" />
    <add key="TestFetchQuoteNo" value="" />
    <add key="TestVersionNo" value=""/>
    <add key="TestProdCode" value="233" />
    <add key="TestSessionID" value="123123"/>
    <add key="TestServiceIP" value="192.168.30.21"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In my case I use APP.XAML to get the value from the app.config in its application_startup.

Answer (score 1):

For Web applications its web.config and for desktop applications its app.config. You can add config files to your project as well.